# parse error in php mysql code cant see the error

Tags: php, mysql, parse-error

Im getting the same  error on two seperate pages involving isset()and cant figure it out.
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in login.php on line 389
line 389 is indicated below
Im trying to connect to a db and store the result in a variable

```
//----get username/ password  values
//if 1
if (isset($_POST['submit']) {
  $usernametxt = $_POST['username'] ;
  $passwordtxt = $_POST['password'];
  $sql = "SELECT username, memberID from members where username = $usernametxt AND password = $passwordtxt";
  $res = mysqli_query($dbcnx, $sql);
  $dbcnx = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "PoolSociety");


     //if 2
    if (mysqli_connect_errno($dbcnx )){
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " .mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
    }//end if 2

         //if 3
        if ( !$res ) {
          echo('Query failed ' . $sql . ' Error:' . mysqli_error());
         exit();

        }else{     
            //if4
            if(mysqli_num_rows($res)< 1){
            //there are no members
           $display_block = "<p><em> No members</em></p>"; 
           }
           else
          {
            $member_info = mysqli_fetch_array($res);
            $username = $member_info['username'];
            $memberID = $member_info['MemberID'];
            $session['username'] = $username;
            $session['memberID'] = $memberID;
            header("location: localMyPage.php");
           } // end if 4
      } //End if 3
}   //end if 1
?>
```

on a second page im getting same parse error on if isset()
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in \Register.php on line 33

```
 if(isset($_POST['submit']) //-----<<<<---line 33
      echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("' . $string . '");</script>';
 }
```

Comment: side note: `/ /----get` is not a valid comment line. You'd also benefit *greatly* by formatting your code properly.

Comment: That is not line 389... if (isset($_POST['submit']) {

Comment: why not just turn on error reporting instead of guessing which line caused it.

Comment: Both sets of `if (isset($_POST['submit'])` are missing the closing parenthesis. It should be `if (isset($_POST['submit']))`. The latter is also missing an opening brace

Comment: And to answer your inevitable next questions; 1) It's because you are running a query before the connection is made, and 2) your query values `$usernametxt` and `$passwordtxt` are unquoted. Use a [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) with bound parameters instead

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a closing brace `}` on your line 389 `if` block.  Take the time to properly format/align your code, it will save you countless headaches, and make it possible for others to support your code in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Your first line that you posted has an error

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']) {
```

You are missing a parentheses, which may be contributing to your overall problem. It should be

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
```

Same thing with the snippet you posted at the very end for line 33, you are missing both an ending parentheses and a curly bracket.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) //-----<<<<---line 33
      echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("' . $string . '");</script>';
 }
```

Should be

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ //-----<<<<---line 33
      echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("' . $string . '");</script>';
 }
```